# Caddy (Linux) CloudFlare Credentials Missing

Tags: linux, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-16.04, cloudflare, caddy

I've just recently started setting up my own Ubuntu v16 server on 100tb.com.  I'm using Caddy to serve my webpages and give my website an SSL certificate for `https`.  I've installed the Cloudflare version of Caddy on set up and have everything configured according to [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-a-website-with-caddy-on-ubuntu-16-04). I have a friend who walked me through setting up Cloudflare so I'm certain it's configured right as well.

The error I'm getting when I restart Caddy is:
`caddy[14965]: Activating privacy features...2018/01/17 17:10:18 CloudFlare credentials missing`

And then Caddy enters a failed state and my website will not show up.  I've tried many things.  I've manually put the `CLOUFLARE_EMAIL` and `CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY` into my `environment` file.  I've used both `env` and `export` to add the credentials to my path variable.  When I run `echo $path` they show up in my path (maybe I put them in wrong tho?).  When I run `echo $CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL` it prints it out to the command line like `myemail@example.com` and same for `echo $CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY`.

I've looked at Caddy's documentation and other people's questions but none had the answer.  I'm not sure why I keep getting this error, I feel like I've done everything correctly.  Thanks in advance for any help/insights you have.

Here is my CaddyFile:

```
www.example.com {
    root /var/www
    gzip
    log /var/www/access.log
    errors /var/www/errors.log
    tls {
        dns cloudflare
    }
}
```

Comment: Credentials don't go in the $PATH variable, they are themselves their own env variables. Try running Caddy simply like this: `CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL=... CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY=... caddy` and that will guarantee that the environment variables are set.

Comment: @Matt It still fails saying Cloudflare credentials are missing.

Comment: When I run printenv I can see both the email and apikey properly defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by editting the caddy.service file under `/etc/systemd/system/caddy.service` adding `Environment=CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY=xxxxx` and `Environment=CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL=xxxxx` below the already existing `Environment=CADDYPATH=xxxxx` and did a `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` followed by `sudo systemctl restart caddy`.  Running `sudo systemctl status caddy.service` shows caddy is running and successfully obtained a ssl certificate, making my website https.

[Source](https://caddy.community/t/cloudflare-credentials-missing/2531)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to edit anything, just put your environment variables before executing the caddy service.

```
export CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL="YOUR_EMAIL_ON_CLOUDFLARE"
export CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY="YOUR_API_KEY_ON_CLOUDFLARE"
```

To check if it saved properly

```
echo $CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL
echo $CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY
```

Then, in the same terminal run

```
sudo CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL=$CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY=$CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY /usr/local/bin/caddy --agree
```

Wait for a few seconds for challenge to finish, and you should see output like this:

```
Activating privacy features... done.
https://example.com
http://example.com
```

This reply gave me a hint. https://caddy.community/t/caddy-and-cloudflare-authentication/3080/4